# Regexp and C# | Split with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings like the following and I need to split the string for this array.  Here are three examples:

```
"4M2V1T"
["4M", "2V", "1T"]

"1V3M1T**3**"
["1V", "3M", "1T**3**"]

"1V**33M**1T"
["1V", **"33M"**, "1T"]
```

Please help me with the right regular expression and split function for that issue.

Comment: in order to split you will need a common delimiter or a set number of characters.  It looks like you want to sometimes tag the number on the end, other times you want to have two numbers in front of the letter.  Thus you can not split what you have using regex.

Comment: Ipsit Gaur, I tried but the major problem is the second and third example. and No, I don't want that you will "Code" for me.  If you don't want to help, just click the "back" button and go to other question.

Comment: Let us know what is the logic of split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting on the following pattern:

```
(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\d+[A-Za-z])
```

This will match any point in the string where what immediately precedes is a letter, and what immediately follows is one or more digits, which in turn are followed by a letter.  This ensures that we only split if we are sure that doing so would generate another bona fide digit-letter group.

```
var items = Regex.Split("4M1L1T3", @"(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\d+[A-Za-z])");
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}

4M
1L
1T3
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, but the second example not as expected: 4M1L1T3 need to be like: [4M, 1L, 1T3].

Comment: @RanAlcobi I updated my answer.  It works on all three test cases now.  If you have other edge cases, then it is bad on you for not telling us what they are.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the '*' chars not belongs to my string (only becouse i tried to bold this area bu somone edit my question... ).  As in my comment: 4M1L1T3 need to be like: [4M, 1L, 1T3].  and thats my major issue

Comment: Works Great!! You are the BEST! Thank you

Comment: @RanAlcobi _Please_ include your code next time, I'm pretty sure you tried something.  Otherwise, folks will view this as a homework dump or something :~(

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot again :)